# Breakdown an integer value to an array of integer maintaining the sum

Tags: convex-optimization, linear-programming, nonlinear-optimization

I am working on a project where I need to breakdown an integer value according to an array of percentage values. 
My end array must contain integer value and the sum of the array must be equal to the initial integer.

For example, I have the integer "7" that I need to split according to an array [0.2, 0.3, 0.5] - the result must be [1, 2, 4] - Similarly, if I have the integer "2" that needs to be breakdown according to the array [0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25] the result can be [0, 0, 1, 1] or any other combination until the sum equal 2.

I managed to create the algorithm that is doing exactly the logic described but I was wondering if such a problem cannot be solved with as a linear programming model. Can anyone help me figure out how to produce such model?

I want to express this problem as a LP model because ultimately the breakdown will be more complex and will involve more complex rules. This example is a toy problem.

How can I formulate mathematically this problem so I can encode it into an optimization framework.

Below is the code of the logic :

```
import numpy as np
from math import isclose, sqrt

def distribute(total, weights):
    scale = float(sum(weights))/total
    return [x / scale for x in weights]

def error_gen(actual, rounded):
    divisor = sqrt(1.0 if actual < 1.0 else actual)
    return abs(rounded - actual) ** 2 / divisor

def round_to_(arr, to):
    if not isclose(sum(arr), to):
        raise ValueError
    n = len(arr)
    rounded = [int(x) for x in arr]
    up_count = to - sum(rounded)
    errors = [(error_gen(arr[i], rounded[i] + 1) - error_gen(arr[i], rounded[i]), i) for i in range(n)]
    rank = sorted(errors)
    for i in range(up_count):
        rounded[rank[i][1]] += 1
    return rounded

if __name__ == "__main__":
    a_case_1 = [.2, .3, .5]
    a_case_2 = [.25, .25, .25, .25]
    a_case_3 = [.25, .25, .5]

    b_case_1 = 7
    b_case_2 = 2
    b_case_3 = 2


    dist_case_1 = distribute(b_case_1, a_case_1)
    print(dist_case_1)
    print(sum(dist_case_1))
    print(round_to_(dist_case_1, b_case_1))

    dist_case_2 = distribute(b_case_2, a_case_2)
    print(dist_case_2)
    print(sum(dist_case_2))
    print(round_to_(dist_case_2, b_case_2))

    dist_case_3 = distribute(b_case_3, a_case_3)
    print(dist_case_3)
    print(sum(dist_case_3))
    print(round_to_(dist_case_3, b_case_3))
```

------------------ [EDIT] ------------------

Based on the excellent feedback from @LinAlg I did try to implement the suggested formulation with Pyomo however the output doesn't seem to produce something meaningful.

This code is using a different example easier to track. We have a list of cars with some "potentials" and we need to allocate this potential to a specific postal code. the postal code allocation is dictated by some sellout information.

```
from pyomo.environ import *


def distribute(total, weights):
    scale = float(sum(weights.values())) / total
    return {k: v / scale for k, v in weights.items()}


Cars = ["car 1", "car 2", "car 3"]
Locations = ["p_code_1", "p_code_2", "p_code_3"]
POTENTIALS = {"car 1": 7, "car 2": 2, "car 3": 14}
SELLOUTS = {"p_code_1": 0.2, "p_code_2": 0.3, "p_code_3": 0.5}

SELLOUTS_PER_P_CODE = {}

for car in Cars:
    pot = POTENTIALS[car]
    scaled_sellout = distribute(pot, SELLOUTS)
    t = {(car, p_code): v for p_code, v in scaled_sellout.items()}
    SELLOUTS_PER_P_CODE.update(t)

model = ConcreteModel(name="Breakdown Potential to Post Code")

model.Cars = Set(initialize=Cars)
model.Locations = Set(initialize=Locations)

model.a = Param(model.Cars, model.Locations, initialize=SELLOUTS_PER_P_CODE)
model.p = Param(model.Cars, initialize=POTENTIALS)

model.X = Var(model.Cars, model.Locations, within=NonNegativeIntegers)
model.T = Var([1, 2], domain=NonNegativeReals)


model.objective = Objective(expr=model.T[1] + model.T[2], sense=minimize)


def t_positive_rule(model, i):
    return (
        sum(model.X[i, j] - model.a[i, j] * model.p[i] for j in model.Locations)
        <= model.T[1]
    )


model.t_positive = Constraint(model.Cars, rule=t_positive_rule)


def t_negative_rule(model, i):
    return (
        sum(model.X[i, j] - model.a[i, j] * model.p[i] for j in model.Locations)
        >= -model.T[2]
    )


model.t_negative = Constraint(model.Cars, rule=t_negative_rule)


def sum_maintained_rule(model, i):
    return sum(model.X[i, j] for j in model.Locations) == model.p[i]


model.sum_maintained = Constraint(model.Cars, rule=sum_maintained_rule)


def pyomo_postprocess(options=None, instance=None, results=None):
    model.pprint()
    model.X.display()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    opt = SolverFactory("glpk")
    results = opt.solve(model)
    results.write()
    print("\nDisplaying Solution\n" + "-" * 80)
    pyomo_postprocess(None, model, results)
```

This code produce the following ouput:

```
Displaying Solution
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
5 Set Declarations
    Cars : Dim=0, Dimen=1, Size=3, Domain=None, Ordered=False, Bounds=None
        ['car 1', 'car 2', 'car 3']
    Locations : Dim=0, Dimen=1, Size=3, Domain=None, Ordered=False, Bounds=None
        ['p_code_1', 'p_code_2', 'p_code_3']
    T_index : Dim=0, Dimen=1, Size=2, Domain=None, Ordered=False, Bounds=(1, 2)
        [1, 2]
    X_index : Dim=0, Dimen=2, Size=9, Domain=None, Ordered=False, Bounds=None
        Virtual
    a_index : Dim=0, Dimen=2, Size=9, Domain=None, Ordered=False, Bounds=None
        Virtual

2 Param Declarations
    a : Size=9, Index=a_index, Domain=Any, Default=None, Mutable=False
        Key                   : Value
        ('car 1', 'p_code_1') : 1.4000000000000001
        ('car 1', 'p_code_2') :                2.1
        ('car 1', 'p_code_3') :                3.5
        ('car 2', 'p_code_1') :                0.4
        ('car 2', 'p_code_2') :                0.6
        ('car 2', 'p_code_3') :                1.0
        ('car 3', 'p_code_1') : 2.8000000000000003
        ('car 3', 'p_code_2') :                4.2
        ('car 3', 'p_code_3') :                7.0
    p : Size=3, Index=Cars, Domain=Any, Default=None, Mutable=False
        Key   : Value
        car 1 :     7
        car 2 :     2
        car 3 :    14

2 Var Declarations
    T : Size=2, Index=T_index
        Key : Lower : Value : Upper : Fixed : Stale : Domain
          1 :     0 :   0.0 :  None : False : False : NonNegativeReals
          2 :     0 : 182.0 :  None : False : False : NonNegativeReals
    X : Size=9, Index=X_index
        Key                   : Lower : Value : Upper : Fixed : Stale : Domain
        ('car 1', 'p_code_1') :     0 :   0.0 :  None : False : False : NonNegativeIntegers
        ('car 1', 'p_code_2') :     0 :   0.0 :  None : False : False : NonNegativeIntegers
        ('car 1', 'p_code_3') :     0 :   7.0 :  None : False : False : NonNegativeIntegers
        ('car 2', 'p_code_1') :     0 :   0.0 :  None : False : False : NonNegativeIntegers
        ('car 2', 'p_code_2') :     0 :   0.0 :  None : False : False : NonNegativeIntegers
        ('car 2', 'p_code_3') :     0 :   2.0 :  None : False : False : NonNegativeIntegers
        ('car 3', 'p_code_1') :     0 :   0.0 :  None : False : False : NonNegativeIntegers
        ('car 3', 'p_code_2') :     0 :   0.0 :  None : False : False : NonNegativeIntegers
        ('car 3', 'p_code_3') :     0 :  14.0 :  None : False : False : NonNegativeIntegers

1 Objective Declarations
    objective : Size=1, Index=None, Active=True
        Key  : Active : Sense    : Expression
        None :   True : minimize : T[1] + T[2]

3 Constraint Declarations
    sum_maintained : Size=3, Index=Cars, Active=True
        Key   : Lower : Body                                                      : Upper : Active
        car 1 :   7.0 : X[car 1,p_code_1] + X[car 1,p_code_2] + X[car 1,p_code_3] :   7.0 :   True
        car 2 :   2.0 : X[car 2,p_code_1] + X[car 2,p_code_2] + X[car 2,p_code_3] :   2.0 :   True
        car 3 :  14.0 : X[car 3,p_code_1] + X[car 3,p_code_2] + X[car 3,p_code_3] :  14.0 :   True
    t_negative : Size=3, Index=Cars, Active=True
        Key   : Lower : Body                                                                                                    : Upper : Active
        car 1 :  -Inf :  - T[2] - (X[car 1,p_code_1] - 9.8 + X[car 1,p_code_2] - 14.700000000000001 + X[car 1,p_code_3] - 24.5) :   0.0 :   True
        car 2 :  -Inf :                  - T[2] - (X[car 2,p_code_1] - 0.8 + X[car 2,p_code_2] - 1.2 + X[car 2,p_code_3] - 2.0) :   0.0 :   True
        car 3 :  -Inf : - T[2] - (X[car 3,p_code_1] - 39.2 + X[car 3,p_code_2] - 58.800000000000004 + X[car 3,p_code_3] - 98.0) :   0.0 :   True
    t_positive : Size=3, Index=Cars, Active=True
        Key   : Lower : Body                                                                                                : Upper : Active
        car 1 :  -Inf :  X[car 1,p_code_1] - 9.8 + X[car 1,p_code_2] - 14.700000000000001 + X[car 1,p_code_3] - 24.5 - T[1] :   0.0 :   True
        car 2 :  -Inf :                  X[car 2,p_code_1] - 0.8 + X[car 2,p_code_2] - 1.2 + X[car 2,p_code_3] - 2.0 - T[1] :   0.0 :   True
        car 3 :  -Inf : X[car 3,p_code_1] - 39.2 + X[car 3,p_code_2] - 58.800000000000004 + X[car 3,p_code_3] - 98.0 - T[1] :   0.0 :   True

13 Declarations: Cars Locations a_index a p X_index X T_index T objective t_positive t_negative sum_maintained
X : Size=9, Index=X_index
    Key                   : Lower : Value : Upper : Fixed : Stale : Domain
    ('car 1', 'p_code_1') :     0 :   0.0 :  None : False : False : NonNegativeIntegers
    ('car 1', 'p_code_2') :     0 :   0.0 :  None : False : False : NonNegativeIntegers
    ('car 1', 'p_code_3') :     0 :   7.0 :  None : False : False : NonNegativeIntegers
    ('car 2', 'p_code_1') :     0 :   0.0 :  None : False : False : NonNegativeIntegers
    ('car 2', 'p_code_2') :     0 :   0.0 :  None : False : False : NonNegativeIntegers
    ('car 2', 'p_code_3') :     0 :   2.0 :  None : False : False : NonNegativeIntegers
    ('car 3', 'p_code_1') :     0 :   0.0 :  None : False : False : NonNegativeIntegers
    ('car 3', 'p_code_2') :     0 :   0.0 :  None : False : False : NonNegativeIntegers
    ('car 3', 'p_code_3') :     0 :  14.0 :  None : False : False : NonNegativeIntegers
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $p$ be your integer and let $a \in [0,1]^n$ be your fractions. An example of a formulation is:

\begin{align}
\min & \sum_{i=1}^n |x_i-a_i p| \\
\text{s.t.} & \sum_{i=1}^n x_i = p \\
& x \in \mathbb{Z}^n_+
\end{align}
The absolute values can be removed with standard methods.

Comment: Thanks. May I ask the thought process. I understand how to transform the absolute value to positive and negative constraints however how come did you get the absolute value?

Comment: you want $a_i p$ to be close to $x_i$, and the absolute value is the only distance measure you can easily represent in a MIP (and I just fixed a mistake: $x$ should be a nonnegative integer)

Comment: I am busy implementing the model in Pyomo (I will update the question with the implementation based on your answer) - I am curious to see how it will handle the case where the a_i are all the same. I guess the model will distribute the integer in the order of the set.

Comment: @Michael due to small numerical errors, I do not think you can predict how the branching will go

Comment: I've edited my initial question with your suggested formulation of the problem using Pyomo - Unfortunately the output does not seem to give meaningful details. Thanks in advance for your valuable input.

Comment: @Michael seems like you messed up with PositiveIntegers vs NonNegativeIntegers ;)

Comment: Hi, thanks! the answer is improved, indeed I should not include the zero... However, the result is pushing one solution and doesn't seem to take into consideration the fraction as a weight factor. I edited the question - Thanks again!

Comment: you need to be more specific in how the fraction should be used as a weight factor

Comment: `SELLOUTS_PER_P_CODE` is dictating the weight to be put for each postal code allocation. For example, for the first car, there is a lot of weight for `p_code_3` and less for `p_code_2` and even less for `p_code_1` so the allocation should be respectively `[1, 2, 4]` - can this be explained as a constraint?

Comment: `[1, 2, 4]` correspond to `[p_code_1, p_code_2, p_code_3]` sorry

Comment: I found the solution, in fact, I should not use the distribute function - in fact, I misunderstood ∈[0,1] - Thanks for your support, I will close this ticket.